# Flask jinja2 function to style specific words when rendering html

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm looking for a function arg for `render_template` or a jinja2 snippet that will bold any words in `words_to_highlight`. Is there a common way to do this?

```
words_to_highlight = set(["bold", "me"])
sentence = "bold me and not the rest"
render_template("index.html", sentence=sentence, words_to_highlight=words_to_highlight)
```

Result:
**bold me** and not the rest

Comment: I would look into a javascript solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as far as I know, since Jinja is about *filling out* or *changing* predefined parts of the document. If you need to apply a highlighting function to the entire document, you will need to look for solutions elsewhere.

A possible solution could be to load the `index.html` as a string and then modify it yourself accordingly before passing it to `render_template`, since it also accepts string.